# Set build action of file copied to project in nuget

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I have a nuget package that copies files into the target project - this is done by adding the following to the nuget project file:

```
<Content Include="Views\Error\Links-Example.cshtml">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

And this will copy the view to the target project views folder

Is there a way to set the build action to none for this copied file (other than manually doing it once it's been copied)?

Comment: You can change `Content` to `None`, this declaration is allowed `<None Include=…>…</None>`

Comment: Ok if I change that to none then it doesn't copy it from the nuget package into the target directory of the project

Comment: You can write your own target to copy the required files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to set the build action to none for this copied file
>   (other than manually doing it once it's been copied)?

It seems what you want is: When one project consumes this package, that file should exist in `VS Solution Explorer`, and its build action should be `None`.

For this, you could use custom [nuspec file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec) when generating the nuget package. Change the `Content` to `None` for your script, and add similar content like mine below into xx.nuspec file:

```
  <metadata>
    ...
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="any/any/Views/Error/controller1.js" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="false" flatten="true" />
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="relativePath/controller1.js" target="contentFiles/any/any/Views/Error/" />
  </files>
```

You can specify the build action of one file in `files` element. And if this package targets .net framework projects, use `Content` instead of `ContentFiles` element.

Then, the copied file's build action can be None when the package is consumed:

[image]